# Constant out of range in comparison C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I just created a C++ problem from my project, I compiled the program and gives me NO ERRORS but gives me a WARNING and I cannot run or test the program.

```
#include <iostreamn.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int grossincome,totaldeduction,tax,output;

    cout<<"Input gross income: "<<endl;
    cin>>grossincome;
    cout<<"Input total deductions: "<<endl;
    cin>>totaldeduction;

    if (grossincome > 100000)
    {
       tax = (grossincome * .20);
       output = (grossincome - totaldeduction - tax);
    }
    else if((grossincome <= 100000) && (grossincome >= 50000))
    {
       tax = (grossincome * .15);
       output = (grossincome - totaldeduction - tax);
    }
    else if(grossincome < 50000)
    {
       tax = (grossincome * .10);
       output = (grossincome - totaldeduction - tax);
    }
    cout<<"Output: "<<output;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I get WARNING in all of my **If statements** saying the message below.

```
  WARNING message: "Warning Q4.CPP 16: Constant out of range in comparison"
                   "Warning Q4.CPP 21: Constant out of range in comparison"
                   "Warning Q4.CPP 21: Constant out of range in comparison"
                   "Warning Q4.CPP 26: Constant out of range in comparison"
```

Comment: whats the size of your `int` type?

Comment: could it be, that sizeof(int) == 2 on your platform?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using Turbo C++ 4.0

Comment: @ChadJimenezCalamba You poor thing... any chance you can convince your teacher to let you guys use a compiler that has been updated in the past 2 decades?

Comment: @CoryKramer - Actually I dont have a choice. lol

Comment: Codeblocks is portable, any way you could put it on a usb, take it to school, and just use it anyways

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turbo C/C++ is an old compiler. The range of int is from -32768 to +32767.
 Either you can switch to a better and standard compiler (like gcc) or use the long modifier.

Comment: 16 bit `int` is acceptable even with C++14 by the way, but it must be 2's complement. But the answer is otherwise correct, plus one.

Comment: Thank you, changing from int to long solves my problem